# Free local (not online) HTML formatter software for Windows

Tags: html, windows, formatting

Do you know any software that can format HTML source code on a Windows based PC (Windows XP) that would be :

- free
- not online (local)
- with user interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favourites would be:

- PsPad (http://www.pspad.com/)
- TextPad (http://www.textpad.com/)

Comment: PsPad is not perfect but it's nice.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to use Notepad++, there is a very powerfull plug-in for that, TextFX.

TextFX can tidy a HTML, but can also do so much more than that.

> TextFX includes numerous features to transform selected text.
>   Featuring: * Interactive Brace Matching * Quote handling * Character
>   case alternation * Text rewrap * Column Lineup * Fill Text Down *
>   Insert counter text down * Text to code conversion * Numeric
>   Conversion * URI & HTML encoding * HTML to text conversion * Submit
>   text to W3C * Text sorting * Ascii Chart * Leading whitespace repair *
>   Autoclose HTML & braces

How to get it?

In your Notepad++ do this:

- Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager
- Enable the checkbox next to TextFX Character
- Press the install button

It's as easy as that.

Answer (score 1):

http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ there is an UI for it but I never tried the UI http://users.rcn.com/creitzel/tidy.html#tidyui it also makes sure your markup is valid. Best tool you can get for this task in my opinion. If the UI is not good I suggest to use it anyways. I don't see a need for an UI for this tool, it easy to use and well documented.